# How can I switch adapter for a Gallery

Tags: android, android-adapter

Is it possible for me to dynamically switch the adapter of a Gallery?

In the `onCreate()` of my activity, I did this:

```
myGallery.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

And then later on in my code, I did

```
myGallery.setAdapter(anotherAdapter1);
```

I tried, that but in the emulator, the myGallery never gets update when I do 'setAdapter' again.
How can I force myGallery free up all the items when it was using adapter1 and then makes it repopulate items for anotherAdapter1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() to the adapter

```
a.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

that will refresh your changes to the gallery view.